# can't get Kotlin to check if variable in listOf

Tags: kotlin

I've tried this 10 different ways and i can't get this to work.
I want this Kotlin code to take in a string, check each character of that string against a listOf characters, and, if it is in that list, increase a counting variable by 1, so then at the end it can check if that counting variable is high enough to pass a test.  this is taken straight from Sololearn: Code Coach - Password Validator.  I have completed this code successfully already in Python (https://code.sololearn.com/c0fl17IMHPfC), but in trying to convert it over to Kotlin, it doesn't seem to work.  The variables don't seem to register as true when compared to the elements in the listOf.

```
fun main() {
    var password: String = readLine()!!
    var numberCount: Int = 0
    var numbers: List<String> = listOf("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")
    var specialCount: Int = 0
    var specialCharacters: List<String> = listOf("!","@","#","$","%","&","*")


    if (password.length < 7) {
        println("Weak")
    } else {
        for (character in password) {
            println(character)
            var numberCheck = numbers.contains(character)
            println(numberCheck)
            if (numberCheck == true) {
                numberCount += 1
            }
            var specialCharactersCheck = specialCharacters.contains(character)
            println(specialCharactersCheck)
            if (specialCharactersCheck == true) {
                specialCount += 1
            }
        }
        println(numberCount)
        println(specialCount)
        if (numberCount < 2) {
            println("Weak")
        } else if (specialCount < 2) {
            println("Weak")
        } else {
            println("Strong")
        }
    }
}
```

When I enter an input of "letssee43$#", the result of this code is:

l
false
false
e
false
false
t
false
false
s
false
false
s
false
false
e
false
false
e
false
false
4
false
false
3
false
false
$
false
false

false
false
0
0
Weak

Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.
Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.

Comment: Why is this tagged as python, if it is a kotlin question

Comment: i put a link to how i completed the code in python, as a reference.  I'm converting this code from python over to Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Lists contain Strings, so every time you call `contains` on them and pass a Char, it will always be false because a Char is not a String.

Probably, the best way to fix it is to declare Iterables of Chars to check them. Lists are Iterables, but so are ranges.

```
val password: String = readln()
var numberCount: Int = 0
val numbers: Iterable<Char> = '0'..'9'
var specialCount: Int = 0
val specialCharacters: List<Char> = listOf('!','@','#','$','%','&','*')
```

And just for your learning, there's a `count` function that takes a lambda argument that can make this kind of task much easier:

```
fun main() {
    val password: String = readln()
    val numbers = '0'..'9'
    val specialCharacters = listOf('!','@','#','$','%','&','*')

    val numberCount: Int = password.count { numbers.contains(it) }
    val specialCount: Int = password.count { specialCharacters.contains(it) }

    val result = when {
        password.length < 7 || numberCount < 2 || specialCount < 2 -> "Weak"
        else -> "Strong"
    }
    println(result)
}
```

Comment: Holy shit that's so much easier and more concise! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is a list of `String`s, but `for (character in password)` loops over the `Char`s in `password`. So you're trying to see if one of the `String`s in your list is a specific `Char`, which it isn't, because they're two different types - a string with a single character in it is still a `String`, not a `Char` (that's why you're getting that type error)

There are lots of ways to do it (and there's nothing wrong with your code besides the `Char`/`String` thing!), personally I'd just do this:

```
var numbers = "0123456789"
var specialCharacters = "!@#$%&*"

val password = "letssee43$#"
val nums = password.count { it in numbers }
val specials = password.count { it in specialCharacters }
println("nums: $nums, specials: $specials")

> nums: 2, specials: 2
```

`count` is iterating over the `Char`s in `password` and counting how many of them each character string contains. A `String` is treated like an array of `Char`s, so you can check it that way. (You could also add `.toList()` after the string declaration if you really want your characters stored in a list - that way it'll be a `List<Char>` so the lookup will still work.)

Or you could do things the way you are, and explicitly write out the `listOf` elements - but make them `Char`s instead, e.g. `listOf('1')` (single quotes) instead of `listOf("1")` (double quotes).

If you *do* want to search a list of strings for a match, you need to provide a `String`, so you need to convert your `Char` to one, e.g. by calling `toString()` on it, using a literal like `"$character"`, etc.

---

**edit** like *gidds* points out below, sets are way more efficient for lookups like `in` or `contains`, so `toSet()` is a better idea than `toList()` unless you really need that ordered list for some reason. If you don't care about efficiency (like if you're not doing a lot of lookups) I'd personally just leave it as a string like in the code block up there - it's nice and simple. But if you *do* want to be more efficient, or if you *do* need a collection (like if you're matching against `String`s) then a `Set` is ideal

Comment: One tweak worth mentioning: `numbers` and `specialCharacters` could be sets rather than strings. (Just call `toSet()` on them.) The benefit is that it can check whether a character is contained in a set in constant time, whereas it has to scan through every character of a string. For short strings as in this example, the time and memory to create the sets probably outweighs any benefit — but as they grow longer a string-based solution will get disproportionately slower, while a set-based one will cope much better.

Comment: @gidds oh yeah definitely - I'll add that in, love me some sets!

Answer (score 0):

I will give you another way to get the same result as you by using Extensions

```
fun main() {
var password: String = readln()
    println("Password contain numbers amount: " + password.containNumbersAmount())
    println("Password contain special characters amount: "+ password.containSpecialCharactersAmount())
    println("Password Status : "+ password.validationResult())
```

}

```
fun String.containNumbersAmount() = count { it.isDigit() }

fun String.containSpecialCharactersAmount(): Int {
val specialCharacters = "!@#$%&*"
return count { it in specialCharacters } }

fun String.validationResult() : String {
return when {
    length < 7 -> "Weak"
    containNumbersAmount() < 2 -> "Weak"
    containSpecialCharactersAmount() < 2 -> "Weak"
    else -> "Strong"
```

}
}